# Wsdl2java behind a proxy: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

I am behind a proxy and the maven cxf plugin is failing to access the `wsdl` file.

**The entry in the `pom.xml` is:**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>-->
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <!--<bindingFiles>-->
                                    <!--<bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bind.xml</bindingFile>-->
                                    <!--</bindingFiles>-->



                                    <!--<wsdl>-->
                                    <!--${basedir}/src/CISInterfaceWSv24.wsdl-->
                                    <!--</wsdl>-->

                                    <wsdl>
                                        http://www.sometestsite.com/interface?wsdl
                                    </wsdl>

                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Below is the stacktrace:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project sg-decide-consult-proxy: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl'.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project sg-decide-consult-proxy: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl'.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java failed: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl'.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl'.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:420)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:414)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:511)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl'.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.build(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:71)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.wsdl11.JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.build(JAXWSDefinitionBuilder.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.testdevelopment.com/interface?wsdl'.: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2422)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.WSDLDefinitionBuilder.parseWSDL(WSDLDefinitionBuilder.java:80)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1535)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2188)
    ... 40 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

I had temporarily solved the problem by adding another step that downloads the wsdl and xsd files. It makes a minor replacement, and then the xsd and wsdl files can be utilized to generate the java.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>
                                        ${basedir}/src/wsdl/interface.wsdl
                                    </wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>download-files</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <!-- download file -->
                            <get src="http://www.testdomain.com/interface?wsdl"
                                 dest="${basedir}/src/wsdl/interface.wsdl"
                                 verbose="false"
                                 usetimestamp="true"/>

                                <!-- download file -->
                                <get src="http://www.testdomain.com/interface?xsd=1"
                                     dest="${basedir}/src/wsdl/interface.xsd"
                                     verbose="false"
                                     usetimestamp="true"/>
                             </target>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <replace token= "http://www.testdomain.com/interface?xsd=1" value="interface.xsd" dir="${basedir}/src/wsdl">
                                <include name="*"/>
                            </replace>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

### Solution 2

I switched to using `importws`. This downloads the file without any problems.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>
                            http://www.development.com/interface?wsdl
                        </wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```